# Is using a member function as an argument to a constructor undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

```
#include <cstdio>

class A
{
public:
    A(int){puts("3");};

    int foo(){puts("4");return 10;}
};

int main()
{
    A a(a.foo());
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs 4 and 3.

It calls a member function before calling the constructor. Is the behavior defined by the standard?

Comment: Yes, this is undefined behaviour. You are calling a member function on a variable that has not yet been initialised.

Comment: `A* bar = NULL;`  `bar->foo();` will also work.. Just so you know. It's undefined though. I also tried something like: `char buffer[256];  A* bar = (A*)&buffer[0];  bar->foo();`  works too.. Still undefined.

Comment: Why is this allowed at all? How come you can access `a` before it's declaration has even finished?

Comment: By the way, the title is somewhat misleading as there is no using any member function as argument.

Comment: @Irfy: There are some datastructures where it makes sense. For instance, a circular buffer may have a ctor which creates the smallest possible buffer, with one Node. This one Node therefore has both Node::next and Node::prev set to `this`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

§12.7 [class.cdtor]/p1:

> For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any
>   non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor
>   begins execution results in undefined behavior.

A conforming compiler is allowed to emit code that blows your legs off.

Comment: What counts as a non-trivial ctor?

Comment: @Davor In essence, any constructor that does something.

Comment: Isn't an empty constructor also non-trivial @T.C. ?

Comment: @LukeB. If user-provided, yes. I was trying to not quote the whole paragraph of the standard specifying what counts as trivial...

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In practice, it may work, because `A::foo` doesn't se any state from `a` instance. You should never write code like this (and you should probably correct it).